# How to convolve a vector with itself n times

Tags: r, algorithm, convolution

Suppose I have a vector x which I want to convolve with itself n times. What is the good way to do this in R?

Suppose that we already have a function conv(u,v) that convolves two vectors.

I can do this:

```
autoconv<-function(x,n){
    r<-1;
    for(i in 1:n){
        r<-conv(r,x);
    }
    return(r);
}
```

is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Note that your function would give the wrong answer for n=0 because `1:0` means `c(1,0)`, not `c()`.

Comment: as far as efficiency goes I think this is OK; if you are routinely going to be computing with n large you can take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the Fast Fourier Transform (fft) of `x`, raise it to the kth power and take the inverse fft.  Then compare that to performing convolutions of `k` copies of `x`.  No packages are used.

```
# set up test data
set.seed(123)
k <- 3 # no of vectors to convolve
n <- 32 # length of x
x <- rnorm(n)

# method 1 using fft and inverse fft
yy <- Re(fft(fft(x)^k, inverse = TRUE) / n)

# method 2 using repeated convolutions
y <- x
if (k >= 2) for(i in 2:k) y <- convolve(x, y, FALSE)

# check that the two methods give the same result
all.equal(y, yy)
## TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
autoconv <- function(x, n){
    if(n == 0){
        return(1)
    } else if(n == 1){
        return(x)
    } else {
        i <- 2
        xi <- conv(x,x)
        while(n %% i != 0){
            i <- i + 1
            xi <- conv(xi,x)
        }
        return(autoconv(xi,n/i))
    }
}
```

This will call `conv()` once for each prime factor of `n`, rather than `n` times.