# Correct way to convolve more than two variables in R

Tags: r, convolution

Is there a correct way to convolute (`convolve()`) more than two variables in `R`? This is a toy dataset:

```
df = data.frame(
    A = c(-0.315, -0.055, -0.017, -1.181, -0.082),
    B = c(-0.159, -0.455, 0.494, -0.672, -0.691),
    C = c(0.408, -0.161, 0.308, 0.305, -0.122),
    D = c(0.371, -0.511, 0.025, -0.107, 0.804)
)
```

I was thinking of convolving the first two, take that result and convolving it with the third, and that result with the fourth and so on. For example:

```
c = convolve(df[,1], df[,2])
c = convolve(c, df[,3])
c = convolve(c, df[,4])
...
```

If this is the correct way, what would be an efficient way to implement this, assuming that the number of columns (variables) can change?

[A Python post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943186/convolve-more-than-two-vectors) with a similar question 
[An R post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270637/how-to-convolve-a-vector-with-itself-n-times) about auto-convolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(convolve, df)
## [1]  0.54181086 -0.04707215  0.26347838  0.54920754 -0.25642045

# check
c <- convolve(df[,1], df[,2])
c <- convolve(c, df[,3])
c <- convolve(c, df[,4])
c
## [1]  0.54181086 -0.04707215  0.26347838  0.54920754 -0.25642045
```

Comment: Hi [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck), following your suggestion, how can I specify the type of `convolve`, for example, `convolve(..., type='open')` or `convolve(..., type='circular')` from `Reduce`? Thanks!

Comment: Define a wrapper function that calls `convolve` or use `purrr:partial` .